# Solve[] isn't producing a correct result

Tags: equation-solving, algebra

I want to find the exact algebraic roots of the following function in terms of `Z`, `P`, `Q`, `F`, and `A`:

```
f(x) = (-2*F*x*Z^2*(P^2 + P*Z + (x*Z)^2)/(P^2 + (x*Z)^2)^(3/2) + 2*x*Z^2*(2*F/Sqrt[P^2 + (x*Z)^2] + 1))*Cos[A + Sqrt[(F^2 + P*Z + Z^2 + (P^2 + P*Z + (x*Z)^2)*(2*F/Sqrt[P^2 + (x*Z)^2] + 1))/(Z*Cos[A])^2 - 1] - Tan[A]]/(2*Z*Cos[A])
 - (1 + F/Sqrt[P^2 + (x*Z)^2])*(x*Z*Cos[Q - x] + P*Sin[Q - x] - Z*Sin[Q - x])
 + (F*x*Z^2*(P*Cos[Q - x] - x*Z*Sin[Q - x]))/(P^2 + (x*Z)^2)^(3/2)
 - Z*Sin[Q - x]
```

I tried inputting `Solve[<THAT EXPRESSION> == 0, x]` in WolframScript, but the expressions it outputs do not line up with the zeroes I can visually see (or numerically calculate) when plotting the function and WolframScript's solutions in GeoGebra. I also tried `Reduce[<THAT EXPRESSION> == 0, x]`, but it ran for an hour without outputting any response.

What is going wrong here? Am I making a mistake somewhere, or am I running into a limitation of the software?

The variables in the function have the following definitions:

- `Q = (F*Sec[A] - P*Tan[A])/Z`
- `P = S - C + F`, and the function in my question is only valid when `P` is negative
- `Z` can be any positive number
- `S` is in the interval `[-1, 1]`
- `C` is in the interval `[1, 1.25]`
- `A` is in the interval `[0, Arccos[4*C/Sqrt[(4*C)^2 + π^2]]]`
- `F` is in both the intervals `[0, (Tan[A] + Sec[A])*(π/4 - C*Tan[A])]` and `[0, (Tan[A] + Sec[A])*Sec[A]*(C - 1)]`

As an example, here is a picture of the function plotted in GeoGebra as a brown curve and the six solutions produced by WolframScript `Solve[]` plotted as complex points. Note that none of the Wolfram points line up with any of the actual x-intercepts of the function:

[image: GeoGebra plot]

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 gives 6 solutions, some are complex.

Comment: If you are plotting then you must be using specific values for all of the parameters. What are these values?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann That's what I'm getting. None of the real or imaginary parts of any of the six solutions line up with the actual zeroes of the function as plotted in GeoGebra.

Comment: @BobHanlon I tried a range of values for each parameter. I've added the relevant information to my question.

Comment: @Lawton Please provide the parameter set which you took in your GeoGebra solution!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I tried the full ranges of values for each parameter, with the proviso that `P` remains negative. Here's a stripped-down version of my project that only has the relevant elements: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WiKMQmoxQdqIFl-relT791X6cxnfhvUN/view

Comment: @Lawton Sorry I have no access to google.drive! For me, one set of parameters (and the GeoGebra result!) would be enough to compare the bot solutions.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Try `z = 8`, `A = 22.5°`, `S = -0.15`, `C = 1.25`, and `F = 0.4`.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Can you access https://www.ztlawton.com/Undercut-Derivative.html (GeoGebra in-browser) or https://www.ztlawton.com/Undercut-Derivative.ggb (GeoGebra file for download)?

Comment: @Lawson Thanks, edited question now is clearer. What's the value of `Q` in GeoGebra simulation ( I took  `0.105896`). You gave me `z==8` but in GeoGebra I see `Z==20`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann With `z == 8`, `Q` should equal `0.1058963053113` as you say. With `z == 20`, `Q` should equal `0.0423585221245`.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I noticed a mistake in the value of `Q` in the GeoGebra file I uploaded. I've fixed it now; you may need to clear your browser cache to see the updated version.

Comment: @Lawton I modified my answer (`z=20`).

Comment: @Lawton Now the results agree quite well !

Answer (score 2):

To long for a comment

`NSolve` evaluates all zeros for given parameter

parameters (from @Larson's GeoGebra picture )

```
subst = {z -> 20, A -> 22.5 \[Degree], S -> -0.15, C -> 1.25, F -> 0.4,
Q -> (F*Sec[A] - P*Tan[A])/z, P -> S - C + F};

f[x_] := ((-2*F*x*z^2*(P^2 + P*z + (x*z)^2)/(P^2 + (x*z)^2)^(3/2) + 
2*x*z^2*(2*F/Sqrt[P^2 + (x*z)^2] + 1))*Cos[A + Sqrt[(F^2 + P*z + 
z^2 + (P^2 + P*z + (x*z)^2)*(2*F/Sqrt[P^2 + (x*z)^2] + 1))/(z*Cos[A])^2 - 1]
- Tan[A]]/(2*z*Cos[A])- (1 + F/Sqrt[P^2 + (x*z)^2])*(x*z*Cos[Q - x] +
P*Sin[Q - x] -z*Sin[Q - x])
+ (F*x*z^2*(P*Cos[Q - x] - x*z*Sin[Q - x]))/(P^2 + (x*z)^2)^(3/2)
- z*Sin[Q - x]) //.subst;

sol = NSolve[{(f[x] //. subst) == 0, -1 < x < 1}, x ,Reals] 
(*{{x -> -0.387626}, {x -> -0.120711}, {x -> 0.244516}} *)

Plot[ f[x] , {x, -1, 1} , GridLines -> {x /. sol , None},PlotRange->{-1,1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I added a picture of my GeoGebra file to my question.

Comment: This does suggest that `NSolve[]` finds the correct solutions; however, I want algebraic solutions, not numeric solutions, and `Solve[]` is still not providing accurate solutions.

Comment: @Lawton `Solve[...]`gives the message "Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information."

Comment: As I said in my question, `Reduce[]` didn't produce an answer even after running for an hour.